# check if text is in file

Tags: bash

my script should check if an Special Word will be in the file, otherweise it should be added to the file

my file:
info.txt

```
info "text1"
```

now my script have These informations:

```
INFO1=$(cat info.txt | grep "info" | head -1 | awk -F "info " '{print $2}' | sed 's/["]//g')
INFO2="info2"
grep info info.txt &>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
sed -i -e "s/^\(info \).*$/\1\"${INFO1}${INFO2}\"/" info.txt
fi
```

now i run this script, then the info.txt will Show me:

```
info "info1 info2"
```

when i run the script again then it gets:

```
info "info1 info2 info2"
```

how can i realize it that the script only add info2 to info.txt when ist not in there? otherwise it should not be added if info2 is in info.txt

Comment: Why check `$?` this way? Just `if ! fgrep -q -e "$INFO2" info.txt; then ...; fi`

Comment: BTW, did you check that this really happens with `info`, `info1` and `info2` rather than your real constants? If the string you were using contained anything that acted as a regular expression that would explain your bug -- but covering up the real values would make it impossible to diagnose.

Comment: The `-q` improves efficiency, because it tells `grep` not to write anything in the first place (and to call its job done whenever it finds the first match) rather than having to scan the whole file but throwing away its output.

Comment: Getting rid of the `$?` reference improves robustness, because it means you can add commands that implicitly change `$?` (like logging) without breaking the flow of program logic, meaning that folks making updates to your code later need to be less careful.

Comment: Using `fgrep` (or `grep -F`) is better than plain `grep` as it forces `"$INFO2"` to be treated as a plain string, not as a regular expression.

Comment: `info`, `info1` and `info2` only for example,

the info field in the txt file will Show something like:

`Information "this is my Information"` now it should be `Information "this in my Information but it's my opinion"` also both are not only one word ist more than 1 word.

Comment: Yes -- that they're examples is why I tell you use to use `fgrep`, since the *real* values could be interpreted as regexes and we wouldn't know from anything you tell us here.

Comment: i try it with `fgrep` my knowledge about bash Scripting is realy not the best.

Comment: That said, even fixing the `grep` won't necessarily fix the `sed` if the actual values are meaningful to `sed` itself. But to debug that, we'd need to _know_ the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your logic:

```
grep info info.txt &>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
sed -i -e "s/^\(info \).*$/\1\"${INFO1}${INFO2}\"/" info.txt
fi
```

This is appending `info2` *only if* `info` is already present. `info` is **always** already present. Thus, it always appends `info2`.

Have your grep look for `info2`, not `info`.

---

See also comments on the question for notes on improving the code. Running it through http://shellcheck.net/ would also be a good  idea.

Answer (score 0):

This adds `$MAGIC_WORD` to `$FILE`, if not present already:

```
FILE=info.txt
MAGIC_WORD=info2

if ! grep -q -e "$MAGIC_WORD" "$FILE" # if the magic word is not in the file
then
  # add the magic word:
  sed -i -e "s/\"\$/ ${MAGIC_WORD}\"/g" "$FILE"
fi
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. The braces around `${file}` don't do anything that enhance correctness (when not immediately followed by other characters valid within variable names), whereas `"$file"` or `"${file}"` would be safer in the presence of filenames with spaces, wildcards in their names, etc.

Comment: (To be clear, that's true for other expansions as well. Also, for `"$magic_word"`, you might want to precede it by `-e` to inform `grep` that it's a value to be matched even if it would otherwise look like a flag or other argument type).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for pointing that out. I will make another edit to address that magic word/flag corner-case as well.

Comment: Better on that count. One might grouse about having regressed on the variable capitalization, on the other hand -- using lower-case variables for non-exported, non-builtin variables as you originally did is in line with convention (the POSIX shell command language specification makes it clear that builtins and environment variables it specifies are all-caps to allow other variable types to avoid namespace conflicts by avoiding that reserved namespace, and suggests that shells adding extensions continue to follow the convention).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Maybe I deliberately chose a different convention than suggested by the specification to distract you from the obvious corner-case my script does not handle ;-)

Comment: thx Michael, with a little bit modifying your code, i done the correct code for me.